# How to test type definition file for react or react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types

I am a maintainer of a react and react-native library/sdk. We also provide type (typescript) definitions for the components that we export. But its a bit hard to manually keep actual components and type definitions in sync, especially when 10 different devs are working on it in parallel. Also its quite hard to test if the provided definitions are accurate without actually using every prop in sample TS project. Has anyone also faced the same issue and/or figured out some easier way to tackle this problem?

What I am looking for is a way to test the type definition file for react type of project.

Comment: Your library is build in typescript or in js and your write `.d.ts` files manually?

Comment: Yeah library is in js. I write .`d.ts` manually

Comment: You could try `dts-gen`. I guess it won't create very accurate definitions file, but it might speed things up